# how to make a current website responsive?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I want to make my current website responsive. It's a huge dynamic website and I do not want to make a separate website for mobile or change the `<Doctype>` or `<html>`. Is it possible to insert a script that changes the `<Doctype>` and `<html>` tags if a website is accessed via a mobile?

Comment: This isn't very clear what you want...

Comment: I'd kill for such a script...

Comment: Are you running PHP or another server-side language? You can detect mobile browser with PHP and serve the page as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to change any tags. This is what [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) are for.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is the best answer and hope it works.

Comment: @themajiks: you must be doing something wrong then. Media queries were designed specifically for responsive design. "A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features. Among the media features that can be used in media queries are ‘width’, ‘height’, and ‘color’. By using media queries, presentations can be tailored to a specific range of output devices without changing the content itself."

Comment: I dont know why its not working sir. can you please check this.
[link](http://www.themajiks.com/test/test.html)

Comment: Well for this you're applying mobile.css to devices with a maximum width of 480px but then overwriting the styling anyway by adding screen.css to *all* devices. A fix for this specific example would be to add mobile.css *after* screen.css.

Comment: Noops. still does't work sir. I have chaged as you said.

Comment: `styles.css` is still being added after `mobile.css`, for me.

Comment: Please try to hard refresh. I am stucked with this. dont know why it is't working for me. can you please help?

Comment: The query works perfectly fine for me now. Ensure that the device you're testing on does indeed have a maximum width of 480px and nothing larger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26378/discussion-between-themajiks-and-james-donnelly)